# How Do I Make Configure EBS To Delete On Termination with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I have created an AMI for a base server image that I would like to deploy when necessary. This base image has the 3 required disks that will be a part of any other server build. However, the additional storage requirements will vary by instance upon creation. I can create and attach this additional storage without issue, but I cannot specify that I want these volumes to delete upon termination of the EC2 instance, and they're currently set to false.

```
$NewInstance = New-EC2Image -ImageID ami-image -InstanceType t2.medium ...
$NewInstanceID = $NewInstance.Instances[0].Id;
$NewVolume = New-EC2Volume -Size 200 -AvailabilityZone "my-fave-az" -VolumeType "gp2";
Add-EC2Volume -InstanceId $NewInstanceID -VolumeId $NewVolume.VolumeId -Device "xvdj";
```

This all works well but I cannot figure out how to set DeleteOnTermination in either

a) The above create script

b) using `Edit-EC2InstanceAttribute` since the attribute is buried at deviceMappings.Ebs.DeleteOnTermination and I cannot figure out how to access that attribute using this commandlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few different patterns, it worked for me to just add an array of Hashtables to the `-BlockDeviceMapping` parameter for `New-EC2Instance`.

I had tried a few different methods, like creating an array of BlockDeviceMapping objects

```
$DeviceMappings = @();
$charmap=100;
foreach($Disk in $Disks)
{
    $volume = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.EbsBlockDevice;
    $volume.VolumeSize = $Disk.Size;
    $volume.VolumeType = "gp2";
    $volume.DeleteOnTermination = $true;

    $DeviceMapping = new-object Amazon.EC2.Model.BlockDeviceMapping;
    $DeviceMapping.DeviceName = "xvd$([char]$charmap)";
    $DeviceMapping.Ebs = $volume;
    $charmap++;
}
```

but that did not work.

What ended up working was this

```
    $DeviceMappings = @();
    $charmap = 100;
    foreach($Disk in $Disks)
    {
        $volume = @{DeviceName="xvd$([char]$charmap)";Ebs=@{VolumeSize=$Disk.Size;DeleteOnTermination="true";VolumeType="gp2"}};
        $DeviceMappings += $volume;
        $charmap++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@swascheck answer gives good clues to this issue, but I wanted to tie a bow on it in case someone else is looking for a packaged answer.

We used this to create our instance.

```
$drives = @()
$eDrive = @{ 
    DeviceName = 'xvdf'
    Ebs = @{
        VolumeSize = 4
        DeleteOnTermination = 'true'
        VolumeType = 'gp2'
    }
}
$fDrive = @{ 
    DeviceName = 'xvdg'
    Ebs = @{
        VolumeSize = 2
        DeleteOnTermination = 'true'
        VolumeType = 'gp2'
    }
}
$drives += $eDrive
$drives += $fDrive

$instances = New-EC2Instance ... -BlockDeviceMapping $drives
```

The -BlockDeviceMapping parameter will cause two extra EC2Volumes to be created with the instance and attached.  They are not complete at that point.  So, we use this on the inside of the VM to ready them for use.

```
Get-Disk -Number 1 | Initialize-Disk -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter 'E' -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'EDrive' -Confirm:$false
Get-Disk -Number 2 | Initialize-Disk -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter 'F' -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'FDrive' -Confirm:$false
```